# SQL Server 2008 Retrieving data query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a query i want to check if in an employee (Table EMPLOYEE) has worked at least one period(periods are in table PERIOD) each month in the past year. After that i want to get the avarage of the days the employee has worked each month. Can anyone provide a solution/explanation?

employee table:

```
USE [MetukisDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TblEmployee]    Script Date: 05/06/2013 23:10:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblEmployee](
    [employeeNumber] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [employeePrivateName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [employeeFamilyName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [city] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [street] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [houseNo] [int] NULL,
    [phoneNumber] [char](10) NULL,
    [birthDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [startWorkingDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [employeeNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblEmployee]  WITH CHECK ADD CHECK  (([employeeNumber] like '[1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblEmployee]  WITH CHECK ADD CHECK  (([houseNo]>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblEmployee]  WITH CHECK ADD CHECK  (([phoneNumber] like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))
GO
```

Period table :

```
USE [MetukisDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TblPeriod]    Script Date: 05/06/2013 23:11:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblPeriod](
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fromDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [toDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblPeriod]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fromDate_check] CHECK  (([fromDate]<=[toDate]))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblPeriod] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fromDate_check]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblPeriod]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Number] CHECK  (([Number]>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblPeriod] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Number]
GO
```

Scheduled table:

```
USE [MetukisDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TblScheduled]    Script Date: 05/07/2013 15:17:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblScheduled](
    [jobNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [employeeNumber] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [machineNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [scheduled_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [jobNumber] ASC,
    [employeeNumber] ASC,
    [machineNumber] ASC,
    [Number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblScheduled]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [certified_period_FK] FOREIGN KEY([jobNumber], [employeeNumber], [machineNumber])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TblCertified] ([jobNumber], [employeeNumber], [machineNumber])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblScheduled] CHECK CONSTRAINT [certified_period_FK]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblScheduled]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Number_FK] FOREIGN KEY([Number])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TblPeriod] ([Number])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblScheduled] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Number_FK]
GO
```

This is what i have so far :

```
select TblEmployee.employeeNumber
from TblEmployee
where(DATEDIFF(year, TblEmployee.birthDate, GETDATE())>25)
select TblSnack.productNumber, TblProduces.machineNumber, TblCertified.employeeNumber 
from TblSnack inner join TblProduces on TblProduces.productNumber= TblSnack.productNumber
inner join TblCertified on TblCertified.machineNumber= TblProduces.machineNumber inner join 
TblChocolate on TblChocolate.productNumber=TblProduces.productNumber
where(TblSnack.containGluten=0) and (TblSnack.containSoy=0)
group by TblProduces.machineNumber, TblCertified.employeeNumber, tblsnack.productNumber
having (COUNT( TblChocolate.productNumber) > 1)
select TblScheduled.Number, TblScheduled.employeeNumber
from TblScheduled
where TblScheduled.Number= (SELECT number 
FROM TblPeriod 
WHERE (MONTH(TblPeriod.fromDate)) = month (dateAdd (month,-1,GETDATE())))
group by TblScheduled.Number, TblScheduled.employeeNumber
```

Comment: How about you go first? Present us with your best effort. Also add your table definitions.

Comment: It's a very long query and this is the one element missing. If i had something to share i would have

Comment: Unless you want your question down-voted and ultimately closed, I strongly suggest you do provide your **relevant** code and your **relevant** data.

Comment: Can a *Period* cross from one month to another?

Comment: A period cannot cross from one month to another

Comment: Your attempt at solving this problem is still missing. Please show us what have you tried, even if you didn't succeed.

Comment: I would think we are also missing an employee work log table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this for your first question:

```
-- Employees who have worked at least one period each month in the past year
SELECT t.employeeNumber,
t.employeeFamilyName
FROM
( SELECT TblEmployee.employeeNumber,
TblEmployee.employeeFamilyName,
COUNT(MONTH(TblPeriod.fromDate)) AS MonthCount
FROM TblEmployee 
JOIN TblScheduled
ON TblScheduled.employeeNumber = TblEmployee.employeeNumber
JOIN TblPeriod 
ON TblPeriod.Number = TblScheduled.Number
WHERE TblPeriod.fromDate >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())
GROUP BY TblEmployee.employeeNumber,
TblEmployee.employeeFamilyName,
MONTH(TblPeriod.fromDate) ) AS t
WHERE t.MonthCount = 12
GROUP BY t.employeeNumber,
t.employeeFamilyName
```

And something like this for the second question:

```
-- Average number of the days the employee has worked each month
SELECT t.employeeNumber,
t.employeeFamilyName,
AVG(t.ScheduleCount) AS AverageCount
FROM
( SELECT TblEmployee.employeeNumber,
TblEmployee.employeeFamilyName,
MONTH(TblPeriod.fromDate) AS PeriodMonth,
COUNT(TblScheduled.Number) AS ScheduleCount
FROM TblEmployee 
JOIN TblScheduled
ON TblScheduled.employeeNumber = TblEmployee.employeeNumber
JOIN TblPeriod 
ON TblPeriod.Number = TblScheduled.Number
WHERE TblPeriod.fromDate >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())
GROUP BY TblEmployee.employeeNumber,
TblEmployee.employeeFamilyName,
MONTH(TblPeriod.fromDate) ) AS t
GROUP BY t.employeeNumber,
t.employeeFamilyName
```

Note how this joins the three tables using foreign keys and primary keys.  The GROUP BY allows us to, e.g., count entries in TblScheduled.

Comment: @user2023203, I added a query for "at least one period each month" and added an average to the "number of days" query.  Also fixed a misplaced comma.  Please let me know if you see any syntax issues.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, however, your solution doesn't work. I always get an avarage of 1 in your query, and i don't get the number of peapole wwho worked for one period a month...

Comment: There can be multiple entries in TblScheduled for each combination of an entry in TblEmployee and an entry in TblPeriod, right?  And there is May data in the system, I hope, because you'll only count 12 months if there is a May entry.

Comment: Yes i have a may entry, and also yes on your first question

Comment: Do the subselects return expected data?  E.g., for the first query, if you run the sub-query inside the parentheses by itself, do you get results like "1, Name1, 2" and "2, Name2, 5", where employee 1 actually worked in two of the months, and employee 2 worked in 5 of the months?

Comment: It works, but it's not giving the right result. In this query I got everithing worked out, except for checking if the employee has worked at least one period a month each mont of the past year